# JMS (Topic) - how can I implement a client as both Producer&Consumer

Tags: swing, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have to design a JMS application with activeMQ. I have 2 clients who should act both as Publishers and Subscribers. E.g. if the first client draws smth., the second client should be able to see it on his GUI and vice versa.

It is clear to me how to "bind" to the server and how to run the activeMQ, I just don't know how to design the client, where to run the SWING and how to send the drawing over. E.G. a Producer would look like this...

```
public class Producer {

private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
private static String subject = "DRAWINGS";

public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false,
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Destination destination = session.createTopic(subject);

    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);


   // how to implement producer as consumer as well and where to create the SWING

   // and bind it to the client?


    connection.close();
}
```

}

Comment: I am in really need of your help...

Answer (score 0):

You create a MessageConsumer the same way you created your MessageProducer like so:

```
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
    consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
        public void onMessage(Message m) {
            // Do something.
        }
    });
```

You'll of course need to keep you main method running via a blocking loop or some just for the purposes of this example, but that's the basics.

Comment: Ok, this sounds good. But how can I make the consumer to be a producer to and vice versa? Like I have 2 clients and they publish and consume at the same time.

Comment: Um, you create a MessageProducer and MessageConsumer in both and produce and let the async consumer consume?

Comment: Now I see my mistake. I was thinking my client is the object `producer` of the class `MessageProducer`, while this object is mainly just a mean to send messages of my client, right? Than i can produce both a publisher and a consumer object inside my client class, right? How about the SWING module, should I integrate it in my client classes, or make a separate class for it? Thank u so much, sometimes one really needs a kick!

Comment: I have no idea on SWING.  Really though that's up to you depending on you application and its requirements.  Most folks generally tend to encapsulate the JMS bits inside wrapper classes that provide interfaces to make their business logic easier.  All depends on what you app needs.